# Creating AppleScript for keystrokes

Tags: keyboard, applescript, script

I've been trying to do my own AppleScript to make my Mac press C 13 times, press the left arrow key, press C 13 times, press the right arrow key and start from the beginning repeatedly at 1.7 seconds intervals.

Currently I have only managed to do a working script that makes it press C multiple times. Could someone please help me with this? This is what I have at the moment

```
set i to 0
repeat while i < 1.0E+300
    set i to i + 1
    delay 1.7
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "c"
end repeat
```

Answer (score 2):

To start off, the number `1.0E+300` is a really ***REALLY*** big number.  That's  more than the number of atoms in the entire universe by several orders.

Your script isn't far off.  To press `"c"` thirteen times, you can either do this:

```
repeat 13 times
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "c"
    -- delay 0.1
end repeat
```

(you potentially need a small delay there to register individual keystrokes, but you can try it without and see which works);

or you can do this:

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "ccccccccccccc"
```

which is the equivalent of the repeat loop *without* the delay.

The left and right arrow keys are `key code 123` and `key code 124`, respectively.  So, adding those in between the keystrokes:

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "ccccccccccccc"
    delay 0.1
    key code 123 -- left arrow
    delay 0.1
    keystroke "ccccccccccccc"
    delay 0.1
    key code 124 -- right arrow
end tell
```

OR:

```
tell application "System Events"
    repeat 13 times
        keystroke "c"
        delay 0.1
    end repeat

    key code 123 -- left arrow
    delay 0.1

    repeat 13 times
        keystroke "c"
        delay 0.1
    end repeat

    key code 124 -- right arrow
end tell
```

Finally, doing this ad infinitum on a loop at 1.7 second intervals, will produce something resembling this:

```
tell application "System Events" to repeat
    repeat 13 times
        keystroke "c"
        delay 0.1
    end repeat

    key code 123 -- left arrow
    delay 0.1

    repeat 13 times
        keystroke "c"
        delay 0.1
    end repeat

    key code 124 -- right arrow

    delay 1.7
end repeat
```

Note that the outside-most repeat loop has no `while`, `until`, or `times` to limit its continuation.  It will loop forever, until you stop the script manually.

I also didn't factor the 0.1-second delays into the overall 1.7-second delay.  The smaller delays will exceed 1.7 seconds in total, but I'll let you adjust the timings to your needs.

Comment: thanks alot! the script works but I found it wasn't able to achieve what I wanted it to. how can I edit the script so I can hold down both arrow keys for 1.5 seconds each time?

Comment: I don't believe that's possible, @kiara.